# How to improve Laravel code using with operator?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

In my request to DB I use Laravel's models and function `with` like:

```
$user = User::with("city")->get();
```

Problem is that if to do the following in template:

```
{{$user->city()->name}}
```

It will work only then if user specified city, so then value exists in database table. Otherwise it returns an error:

How to get rid of superfluous checks like:

```
@if(isset($user->city()->name))
   {{$user->city()->name}}
@endif
```

This is awfully!

Comment: BTW, you gain access to the related model via a property, not via a method. So use `$user->city->name`, not `$user->city()->name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When defining the relationship on your model, use the `withDefault` method:

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(City::class)->withDefault();
    }
}
```

With this in place, `$user->city` will always return a `City` model.

Comment: This is does not work jointly with `return $this->belongsToMany();`?

Comment: I use Laravel 5.4

Comment: @Darama - `belongsToMany` always returns a collection. Your original example didn't show you using a collection. And since it uses a collection, it always returns a collection (empty if there are no related models). So you never have to check anything.